# SoftLayer API: order a 128 subnet

Tags: python-2.7, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are trying to order a 128 subnet. But looks like it doesn't work, get an error saying `Invalid combination specified for ordering a subnet`. The same code works to order a 64 subnet. Any thoughts how to order a 128 subnet? 

`network_mgr = SoftLayer.managers.network.NetworkManager(client)
network_mgr.add_subnet(‘private’, 128, vlan_id, test_order=True)`

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subnet.py", line 11, in <module>
    result = nwmgr.add_subnet('private', 128, vlan_id, test_order=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/managers/network.py", line 154, in add_subnet
    raise TypeError('Invalid combination specified for ordering a'
TypeError: Invalid combination specified for ordering a subnet.`

Answer (score 0):

Currently it seems not possible to add 128 ip subnet into the order, the package used by the manager to order subnets only allows to add subnets for: 64,32,16,8,4 (capacity),

It is because the package that does not contain any item that has 128 ip addresses subnet, this is the reason why you are getting the error Exception you provided.

You may also verify this through the Portal UI, if you can see 128 ip address option through UI in your account, please update this forum with a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We just tried with another SoftLayer account, the above code works well. and this option is available on Portal UI as well. So looks like it's related to SoftLayer account, do you know how to check whether this is available for a specific account? Thanks.